# Shading show triangles on quads

Tags: shaders

Is there any option that could fix this triangles?
[image]

They are subtle but unfortunatelly still could be seen in Substance and later on texturised model. This is how topology and substance looks:
[image]

I tried to bake this, a lot more poligon heavy chain, to fix this triangles, but it's not helping :(
[image]

Comment: Hello please share one of these objects: blend-exchange.com

Comment: All meshes are triangularized at render time, there's no way around that. But baking a higher density mesh's normal map can help fake the details. Also consider how close the camera has to be to see the issue.